# I already have a natty-desktop-amd64.iso downloaded and on my system. How can I tell vmbuilder to use it?

Tags: 11.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I already have a natty-desktop-amd64.iso downloaded and on my system. How can I tell vmbuilder to use it?

vmbuilder seems to be using wget to download debs itself. is there a way to get it to use debs out of an iso? maybe a loopback mounted iso?

update: I'm running natty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `vmbuilder <hypervisor> ubuntu --help` it output an help page in which I read

```
--iso=PATH          Use an iso image as the source for installation of file. Full path to the iso must be provided. If --mirror is also provided, it
                    will be used in the final sources.list of the vm.  This requires suite and kernel parameter to match what is available on the iso,
                    obviously.
```

I'm not tried it, though.

Comment: This is not in the man page, nor is it in my vmbuilder --help output. Perhaps you are running on oneric and this option was added since natty?

Comment: @Jay _silly_evarlast_ Wren: i'm using natty, and i write down the (almost) exact command in my answer: you only need to substitute `<hypervisor>` with a real value, one of `xen kvm vmw6 vmserver`

Comment: To clarify, note that `vmbuilder --help` does not include the `--iso` option, while `vmbuilder kvm ubuntu --help` does.