# Specifying a local iso to vmbuilder for KVM

Tags: virtualization, iso, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to specify a local `.iso` image of the Ubuntu OS I would like to use to create a virtual machine of. According to `vmbuilder kvm ubuntu --help`, (and [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56205/i-already-have-a-natty-desktop-amd64-iso-downloaded-and-on-my-system-how-can-i)) you are allowed to specify an `.iso` file instead of using a mirror.

I have downloaded my own copy of Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 i386 from Ubuntu.com and tried to specify it like so

```
vmbuilder kvm ubuntu --suite=precise --arch=i386 -o --flavour=server --iso=/home/fred/Desktop/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso --libvirt=qemu:///system --ip=192.168.1.39 --gw=192.168.1.254 --part=vmbuilder.partition --templates=mytemplates --user=fred --name=fred --pass=password --mem=1024 --cpu=1 --hostname=vm1 --bridge=br0
```

I have tried replacing `--flavour=server` with `--flavour=desktop, --flavour=virtual` and nothing at all.

The help command states

```
--iso=PATH       This requires suite and
                 kernel parameter to match what is available on the
                 iso, obviously.
```

which makes me think I could be getting the `--flavour` or `--suite` option wrong though I don't understand how or why.

I ran it with the `--debug` command and pasted the output on pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/dtVAmSv1). Mainly it's failing to create the image because:

```
Failure trying to run: chroot /tmp/tmp6UfExa mount -t proc proc /proc
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be a very local issue (ie something quirky on your machine). I had a similar issue and it was to do with a type on one of the switches and not a mounting issue at all. But...

If you're running 12.04 yourself you shouldn't need to specif the iso. You have already told the application you want to install the 'precise' suite (ie 12.04) and you should probably `--flavour=virtual` (that's the joy of vmbuilder - no need to download the isos if you just want Ubuntu. Try simplifying your command even if it creates an image you late have to delete because it is unusable or not enough memory. You can start with something as simple as

```
vmbuilder kvm ubuntu
```

and if you want it 'virsh'-compatible or specify memory etc then yes add the appropriate switch:

```
vmbuilder kvm ubuntu --suite=precise --mem=1024 --flavour=virtual -o --libvirt qemu:///system --user=admin --pass=myPassw0rd
```

I also find that despite configuring things in what I believe is the same way, I sometimes find I have to move my image files to a different directory in `/var/lib/libvirt`.

Add the bridge, `--addpkg acpid` (if you want to be able to shutdown an ubuntu instance correctly, openssh-server is good too allowing you to access the machine other than via VNC/screen scraping.

Enjoy